# Trying to understand iid

Tags: independence, iid

Suppose that I have a sequence of random variables $\{X_i,Y_{it}\}_{i=1,t=1}^{N,T}$. I want to assume i.i.d with this sequence of random variables. So I wonder it is correct to assume

1. $\{X_i,Y_{it}\}_{i=1}^N$ i.i.d.
2. $\{X_i,Y_{it}\}_{i=1,t=1}^{N,T}$ i.i.d.

I am not sure if I can make either of assumptions because $X_{i}$ is indexed by $i$ alone and $Y_{it}$ is indexed by both $i$ and $t$.

Comment: Is it that, you have $N*T$ random vectors in your sequence (where each vector is $(X_i,Y_{it})$). Now how can $(X_1, Y_{11})$ and $(X_1,Y_{12})$ be independent?

Comment: @Dayne I see, but $(X_1,Y_{11})$ and $(X_2,Y_{21})$ can be indepdnent right?

Comment: of course, because now there are no common random variables so if you are defining the relationship yourself you are free to make them independent.

Comment: Your notation is nonstandard and ambiguous: please explain what it means.  In particular, are your random variables univariate or vectors or matrices or something else?

Comment: @whuber they are univariate random variables. Am I not sure how the question will change if they were vectors instead.

Comment: When vectors are *iid,* their components need not be *iid.* Take, for instance, an *iid* sample $(X_1,Y_1), (X_2,Y_2), \ldots, (X_n,Y_n)$ from a Binormal distribution having nonzero correlation coefficient.  Every $Y_i$ is correlated with its corresponding $X_i,$ demonstrating those pairs are not independent.  This is why you need to be *very* clear about your assumptions.